# Connection DSNless table to SQL Server backend hosted on Azure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, server, dsn

I built an Access database for my wife's company a couple of years ago and then when COVID started, they all started working from home via VPN.  Subsequently, Access was no longer a plausible solution so I have moved the backend into an SQL server instance hosted on Azure.

Everything works fine from my home office and my wife's but, when her employees try to login, they get the ODBC--call failed error.

I have narrowed the problem down and I believe that the issue is driver related.  Code is listed below but: when I change stDriver to

> "ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"

then my copy works but employee's do not.  Assuming that not all the employees will have this installed on their computers, I am trying to code in

> "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server}"

which fails on my end with the ODBC--call failed (error 3146).

I have built the code to read the installed drivers from the local machine and I can confirm that my computer has SQL Server installed as a driver as do the employees.

If anyone can help alleviate the call failed error when using SQL Server instead of Driver 17, that would be super appreciated so that I can get on with testing (and the rest of my life).

Be advised that this function has been subject to like 8 hours of troubleshooting so forgive the form as is.

```
Function AttachDSNLessTable(stLocalTableName As String) As Boolean
'Create a linked table to SQL Server with no DSN
Dim td As TableDef
Dim stConnect As String 'Full connection string
Dim stRemoteTableName As String 'table that you are linking to on the backend
Dim stDriver As String 'name of driver found in registry

stRemoteTableName = "dbo." & stLocalTableName
stDriver = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server}" '-----------PROBLEM HERE-----------

On Error Resume Next
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
If Err.Number = 3265 Then

    If Len(STUSERNAME) = 0 Then
        'Use trusted authentication if stUsername is not supplied.
        stConnect = stDriver & ";SERVER=" & STSERVER & ";DATABASE=" & STDATABASE & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    Else
        'WARNING: This will save the username and the password with the linked table information.
        stConnect = stDriver & ";SERVER=" & STSERVER & ";DATABASE=" & STDATABASE & ";UID=" & STUSERNAME & ";PWD=" & STPASSWORD
    End If
    On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td '------------FAILS HERE---------
    
    AttachDSNLessTable = True
    Exit Function

Else
    Debug.Print Err.Number
End If

AttachDSNLessTable_Err:
AttachDSNLessTable = False
    MsgBox "AttachDSNLessTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description & Err.Number
    
End Function
```

Comment: The solution is to install the newer ODBC driver on your clients' machines. Don't use the "SQL Server" driver that ships with windows; it's intended to be used only for legacy applications.

Comment: upvoted the above comment. I mean, you can try linking on your computer using the legacy drivers, but to my knowledge they can't be used with Azure. You need to use one of the newer native drivers - like nc17. They also have speical provision for connecting over the internet, and ODBC fails with the legacy drivers will not be reliable at all. So, yes, you have to be 100% sure that the SAME drivers are installed on each workstation. - as noted, use 17 or 18. They are designed specific to work with Azure where as the legacy one is not.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but effective nonetheless.  Thanks for your help!